# Wso2 mailto transport emptied my Inbox

Tags: wso2, mailto, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I was working with the wso2 esb mail transport. I configured my mail id and all the details in the axis2.xml. When I restarted the Wso2 esb, I found that my Inbox is emptied.

**Here is my axix2.xml:**

```html
    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--             Transport Ins (Listeners)             -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->

 <transportReceiver name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportListener">
        <!-- configure any optional POP3/IMAP properties
        check com.sun.mail.pop3 and com.sun.mail.imap package documentation for more details-->
    </transportReceiver>

    <!-- ================================================= -->
    <!--             Transport Outs (Senders)              -->
    <!-- ================================================= -->

    <!-- Uncomment and configure the SMTP server information
    check com.sun.mail.smtp package documentation for descriptions of properties-->
    <transportSender name="mailto" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.mail.MailTransportSender">
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.host">mum.*******.com</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.port">587</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.auth">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.user">*******</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.password">*********</parameter>
        <parameter name="mail.smtp.from">*******@*****.com</parameter>
    </transportSender>
```

**Here is my proxy:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="MailSample"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log>
            <property name="hii" value="hi************************"/>
         </log>
         <property name="senderAddress" expression="get-property('transport', 'From')"/>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="Sender Address" expression="get-property('senderAddress')"/>
         </log>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="mailto:janiyani.richa@gmail.com"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>application/xml</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">mailSender</parameter>
</proxy>
```

Do you know where did my mails go? 
Is it possible to retrieve the mails?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, most POP3 mail servers keep messages only until they are downloaded by the mail client and then those are deleted. So the above behaviour can be due to that reason and you can prevent this from happening by doing the necessary configurations to leave the messages on server without deleting them even after they are read.

For setting this property at the client (axis2) side, see the `mail.pop3.rsetbeforequit` property in the com.sun.mail.pop3 documentation [available here](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html). (Also depending on the server, there can be server side configurations instead that will make sure that mails will always be kept at the server after being read.)